# Python OpenCV for template matching

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, template-matching

I have a small python script using openCV that does template matching in an image and nicely returns a bounding box, as bellow. The script is size invariant as well which makes it more robust.

Given the bounding box returned, how can I **replace** it with another template and save the altered image?

Here is the [original template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqXno.png) and the [main image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxb6V.jpg)

[image]

And now I would like to simply replace the exact box with a resized version of template2 below, and save the new image. How can I do that?

[image]

Here is my simple code:

```
# USAGE
# python match.py --template cod_logo.png --images images

# import the necessary packages
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import glob
import cv2

# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-t", "--template", required=True, help="Path to template image")
ap.add_argument("-i", "--images", required=True,
    help="Path to images dir where template will be matched")
ap.add_argument("-v", "--visualize",
    help="Flag 0 or 1 indicating whether or not to visualize each iteration")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# load the image image, convert it to grayscale, and detect edges
template = cv2.imread(args["template"])
template = cv2.cvtColor(template, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
template = cv2.Canny(template, 50, 200)
(tH, tW) = template.shape[:2]
cv2.imshow("Template", template)

# loop over the images to find the template in
for imagePath in glob.glob(args["images"] + "/*.*"):
    # load the image, convert it to grayscale, and initialize the
    # bookkeeping variable to keep track of the matched region
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    found = None

    # loop over the scales of the image
    for scale in np.linspace(0.2, 1.0, 20)[::-1]:
        # resize the image according to the scale, and keep track
        # of the ratio of the resizing
        resized = imutils.resize(gray, width = int(gray.shape[1] * scale))
        r = gray.shape[1] / float(resized.shape[1])

        # if the resized image is smaller than the template, then break
        # from the loop
        if resized.shape[0] < tH or resized.shape[1] < tW:
            break

        # detect edges in the resized, grayscale image and apply template
        # matching to find the template in the image
        edged = cv2.Canny(resized, 50, 200)
        result = cv2.matchTemplate(edged, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF)
        (_, maxVal, _, maxLoc) = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)

        # check to see if the iteration should be visualized
        if args.get("visualize", False):
            # draw a bounding box around the detected region
            clone = np.dstack([edged, edged, edged])
            cv2.rectangle(clone, (maxLoc[0], maxLoc[1]),
                (maxLoc[0] + tW, maxLoc[1] + tH), (0, 0, 255), 2)
            cv2.imshow("Visualize", clone)
            cv2.waitKey(0)

        # if we have found a new maximum correlation value, then ipdate
        # the bookkeeping variable
        if found is None or maxVal > found[0]:
            found = (maxVal, maxLoc, r)

    # unpack the bookkeeping varaible and compute the (x, y) coordinates
    # of the bounding box based on the resized ratio
    (_, maxLoc, r) = found
    (startX, startY) = (int(maxLoc[0] * r), int(maxLoc[1] * r))
    (endX, endY) = (int((maxLoc[0] + tW) * r), int((maxLoc[1] + tH) * r))

    # draw a bounding box around the detected result and display the image
    cv2.rectangle(image, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), (0, 0, 255), 2)
    cv2.imshow("Image", image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: So, do you simply want to replace the image without worrying about proper blending or you would like to have just the text appear and rest of the background remain the same? Later one is a much involved task. Resizing and fitting the replacement image should be fairly simple but your image would have that fake image look.

Comment: Yes just the simple approach for now.

Comment: If that's the case then you have almost everything in your code already. All you need to do once you find a matching template is to read the replacement image, resize it to the size of the template image (given aspect ratios are same for both or else you might have to resize it such that your replacement hides template completely) and then do something like image[startY:endY, startX:endX, :] = replacement_img (this has the size endX-startX, endY-startY). Have I misconstrued what you want to do?

Comment: Yes I kinda did it, but using PIL. And I have to convert cv2 to PIL and reverse. And I'm trying it on video frames, but it's very shaky. Is there any ways to remove the shakes?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you need to do this juggling between PIL and cv2? Can't you just use opencv (my understanding is that opencv is in some/most cases faster than PIL)? You can try template matching on smaller sized samples of your source image and templates to speed up. Also, if you have any rectangle drawing code, try removing that code as well. You might need to provide the code that you are using for video processing. But what I have mentioned could be used as a starting point.

Comment: No real reason! I didn't find the opencv equivalent for resize and paste so just used the PIL version! If you know a cv solution, please let me know!

Comment: Paste I already mentioned in one of my previous comments. Here's resize img_resized = cv2.resize(img, (width, height),0,0,cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

Comment: @KnightForked I'll try to share the video code that is a bit shaky after replacement over multiple frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some changes ...

1] I'm not using argument parser

2] tepmlate2 is COUNTER STRIKE.

3] Image2 is the image in which COUNTER STRIKE IS ON TOP OF COD.

> STEPS : Extracting roi (region of interest) , then resizing the new
> image accordingly ... , then operlapping roi with new resized image,
> placing roi back on the image2.
>
> **Advantage => you can change the opacity of the roi and template by
> changing alpha and beta in addWeighted.**

```
# USAGE
# python match.py --template cod_logo.png --images images

# import the necessary packages
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import glob
import cv2

#New template
template2 = cv2.imread("template2.png")

# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
# ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
# ap.add_argument("-t", "--template", required=True, help="Path to template image")
# ap.add_argument("-i", "--images", required=True,
#     help="Path to images dir where template will be matched")
# ap.add_argument("-v", "--visualize",
#     help="Flag 0 or 1 indicating whether or not to visualize each iteration")
# args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# load the image image, convert it to grayscale, and detect edges
template = cv2.imread("template.png")
template = cv2.cvtColor(template, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
template = cv2.Canny(template, 50, 200)
(tH, tW) = template.shape\[:2\]
cv2.imshow("Template", template)

# loop over the images to find the template in
#for imagePath in glob.glob(args\["images"\] + "/*.*"):
    # load the image, convert it to grayscale, and initialize the
    # bookkeeping variable to keep track of the matched region
image = cv2.imread("mainImage.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
found = None

# loop over the scales of the image
for scale in np.linspace(0.2, 1.0, 20)\[::-1\]:
    # resize the image according to the scale, and keep track
    # of the ratio of the resizing
    resized = imutils.resize(gray, width = int(gray.shape\[1\] * scale))
    r = gray.shape\[1\] / float(resized.shape\[1\])

    # if the resized image is smaller than the template, then break
    # from the loop
    if resized.shape\[0\] < tH or resized.shape\[1\] < tW:
        break

    # detect edges in the resized, grayscale image and apply template
    # matching to find the template in the image
    edged = cv2.Canny(resized, 50, 200)
    result = cv2.matchTemplate(edged, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF)
    (_, maxVal, _, maxLoc) = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)

    # check to see if the iteration should be visualized
    '''
    if args.get("visualize", False):
        # draw a bounding box around the detected region
        clone = np.dstack(\[edged, edged, edged\])
        cv2.rectangle(clone, (maxLoc\[0\], maxLoc\[1\]),
            (maxLoc\[0\] + tW, maxLoc\[1\] + tH), (0, 0, 255), 2)
        cv2.imshow("Visualize", clone)
        cv2.waitKey(0)'''

    # if we have found a new maximum correlation value, then ipdate
    # the bookkeeping variable
    if found is None or maxVal > found\[0\]:
        found = (maxVal, maxLoc, r)

# unpack the bookkeeping varaible and compute the (x, y) coordinates
# of the bounding box based on the resized ratio
(_, maxLoc, r) = found
(startX, startY) = (int(maxLoc\[0\] * r), int(maxLoc\[1\] * r))
(endX, endY) = (int((maxLoc\[0\] + tW) * r), int((maxLoc\[1\] + tH) * r))

#MY CODE
image2 = image.copy()
resizedTemplate = cv2.resize(template2, (endX-startX, endY-startY), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
roi = image2[startY:endY, startX:endX]
img = cv2.addWeighted(resizedTemplate, 1, roi, 0, 0)
image2[startY:endY, startX:endX] = img


# draw a bounding box around the detected result and display the image
cv2.rectangle(image, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), (0, 0, 128), 2)
cv2.imshow("Image", image)
cv2.imshow("Image2", image2)
#cv2.imshow("resizedTemplate", resizedTemplate)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frfXQ.jpg)

Comment: Thanks. One error was because of `\[` says `Lexical error at line 80, column 9.  Encountered: "[" (91), after : "\\"`. Removed the `\` and it was fixed.

Comment: For some reason "\"  was added before "[" and "]". But the code is correct, you can resolve those small errors :).

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is ...

1] Use [addWeighted](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html) to place another image on top of the original image.

> cv2.addWeighted(src1, alpha, src2, beta, gamma[, dst[, dtype]])

You can use cv2.add() as well, cv2.addWeighted() is used for blending and giving different transparency.

NOTE : Size of area you are cropping out and size of new image with whom you want to replace MUST BE SAME.

Comment: Ya sure, gust give me a minute.